# Refresh Kendo UI grid data by reading a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Grid reads data from a javascript variable.

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "text",
        data: jsvar,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id: {type: "string", editable: false},
                    name: {type: "string"}
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20
    },
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: true
    },
   //toolbar: [{text: "Add"}],
    columns: [
        {command: [{text: "Edit", click: showDetailse}, {text: "View", click: viewoneitm}], title: "&nbsp;", width: "170px"},


    ]
});
```

Then I change value of this variable jsvar with ajax and wait for ajax response and after that when I refresh grid with

```
            jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

The grid is not repopulated with new data and old data stays in grid. Please tell me how to refresh grid data.
This worked fine and grid used to refresh perfectly untill I proviced static data, but after I used ajax and then 'refresh' it failed to update

Comment: I am badly stuck in this, any kind of help will be much appreciated. I can share complete code if someone is interested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `jsvar` contains an array, the Kendo data source will create a model for each array item, so if you modify the original array, it won't change the DataSource. If you want to change the data, you should do it like this:

```
grid.dataSource.data(jsvar);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lars, you saved my day. It worked!!!
            `jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(jsdatax);
jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();`

Comment: Using angularjs you can use something like: 
<div data-kendo-grid="grid" ... />
$scope.grid.dataSource.data($scope.jsdatax);
$scope.grid.refresh();